# RSS Feed web tiles only update when I sync it with Health App

Tags: microsoft-band

Web tiles with rss feeds are not syncing unless I open the Health App? Alerts are also only push while syncing the band with Health App.

Running the Health App on Windows Mobile build 10581.

Answer (score 0):

The background component of the Health app will check for updates to Web Tiles every 15 - 30 minutes. The Health app does not need to be running for these periodic updates to occur.